# Appexchange listing and security review

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

I had a few questions regarding appexchange listing and security review of a managed package:

1. Can you modify the appexchange listing while the managed package is in security review?
2. What happens when you 'publish listing' before the package has passed the security review?
3. Are there any parts of the listing that gets locked once the review is in progress?
4. Can you continue developing your managed package and release newer release/beta versions of the package while the review is in progess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you modify the appexchange listing while the managed package is in security review?

Yes, you can. You should not modify the pricing (from free to paid, or the other way around), but you can add media, change the name, and so on.

> What happens when you 'publish listing' before the package has passed the security review?

It is no longer a "private" listing and can be searched. The security review adds a special badge to your app that identifies it as security-reviewed, but does not affect your published status.

> Are there any parts of the listing that gets locked once the review is in progress?

As far as I'm aware, no. You can continue to add media, change the description and pricing details, publish and unpublish your listing, and so on during the review process.

> Can you continue developing your managed package and release newer release/beta versions of the package while the review is in progess?

Yes. The review process is against a particular version of your app. During the year window following a review, you can apply the security-reviewed flag to later versions of your code, but versions lower than the one submitted for review may not be automatically security-reviewed.

Comment: Thanks so much! You mentioned that one can publish/unpublish the listing..does that mean you can hide an existing public listing? Does that affect the agreement with salesforce as a checkout partner?

Comment: @Tan You'll want to confirm with partner support, but my understanding is that the published status doesn't affect anything other than the visibility of the listing. Security review, partnership status, and listing status are generally three independent things.